# Is Pidgin integrated with Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, pidgin

Does Pidgin integrate well with Gnome Shell, compared to Empathy? I'm using Linux Mint 12 right now. Would I be better off installing Empathy?

Answer (score 3):

There is a "gnome-shell-extensions-pidgin" referred on [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extension).

It will allow some synchronization between Pidgin and gnome-shell.

Personally, I believe Empathy isn't still ready for the masses.